# How can i create dynamic buttons on button click event (C sharp ASP.NET)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, dynamic, controls

I want to create dynamic buttons on button click event(for example., btnCreateDynamic_Click).
I tried creating dynamic buttons on page_load event and Pre_int event.They are all working but i want to create them in button click event. How can i do this in c# asp.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea would be to create a list of buttons in which you'd store the buttons you created in btnCreateDynamic_click.

you could have a method like:

```
private Button CreateButton(string id, string name)
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Text = name;
            b.ID = id;
            b.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
            b.OnClientClick = "ButtonClick('" + b.ClientID + "')";
            return b;
        }
```

in btnCreateDynamic_click you could have something like:

```
Button b = CreateButton("dinamicBtn"+myDinamicButtonsList.Count.ToString(),"dinamicBtn"+myDinamicButtonsList.Count.ToString());
myDinamicButtonsList.add(b);
```

and in the pageLoad for example you could do something like

```
foreach(button btn in myDinamicButtonsList){
    form1.Controls.Add(btn));
}

List<Button> myDinamicButtonsList = new List<Button>();
```

myDinamicButtonsList should be stored somewhere from where it could be retrieved after each request.

**EDIT**:
In page load you could have something like this:

```
if(Session["myDinamicButtons"] == null){
    List<Button> myDinamicButtonsList = new List<Button>();
    Session["myDinamicButtons"] = myDinamicButtonsList;
}

foreach(Button btn in Session["myDinamicButtons"] as List<Button>){
    form1.Controls.Add(btn));
}
```

i didn't tested it but it should work.

Comment: (As im not familier with list)Can i store the buttons in arraylist instead of List? I tried but i got error. Would you please help?

Comment: you can create the list this: List<Button> myDinamicButtonsList = new List<Button>(); you have to think where you could store it in order to have access to it every time the page reloads. you could add it in a session variable like this Session["myDinamicButtonsList"] = myDinamicButtonsList; and retrieve it from there on each page load. just an idea..

Answer (score 2):

Your button click event at the client will cause a page postback that will start the ASP.Net Page Life-cycle;
[image]

Your button click event on the server is a PostBackEvent and you should be able to use the same method call `CreateMyButton()` that you used in the Load or Init events.